# Sci-fi movie with aliens, where blood was coming out of overhead pipes

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

A movie, likely from 1950s or very early 1960s.  I believe it was with aliens.  When a couple of the characters were walking through what I remember looked like some factory/facility, blood was dripping onto the floor.  It was coming from an overhead pipe.  It was apparently from a group member that was placed in the pipe (pressurized?).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this movie black & white, or in colour? Also, which country and language did you watch it in?

Comment: We only had a b&w tv, so not entirely sure.  Given the age of movie, likely b&w.  Seen in US in English.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is ***[Quatermass 2](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050873/?ref_=ttgf_gf_tt)*** (1957).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quatermass_2):

> *Quatermass 2* (a.k.a. *Enemy From Space* in the United States and Canada) is a 1957 black-and-white British science fiction horror film drama from Hammer Film Productions, produced by Anthony Hinds, directed by Val Guest, that stars Brian Donlevy, and co-stars John Longden, Sidney James, Bryan Forbes, Vera Day, and William Franklyn. Quatermass 2 is a sequel to Hammer's earlier film The Quatermass Xperiment (1955). It was originally shown in the UK as Quatermass II. Like its predecessor, it is based on the BBC Television serial Quatermass II written by Nigel Kneale. Brian Donlevy reprises his role as the eponymous Professor Bernard Quatermass, making him the only actor to play the character twice in a film. It is considered as the first film sequel to use the ‘2’ / ‘II’ suffix within the title.
>
> The film's storyline concerns Quatermass's investigation of reports of hundreds of meteorites landing only in the Winnerden Flats area of the UK. His inquiries lead him to **a huge industrial complex, strikingly similar to his own plans for a Moon colony. This top-secret facility is in fact the centre of a conspiracy involving the alien infiltration of the highest echelons of the British Government.** Quatermass and his allies must now do whatever is necessary to defeat the alien threat before it is too late.

[This review](https://classichorrors.wordpress.com/2016/10/05/hammer-sci-fi-quatermass-2-aka-enemy-from-space-1957/) mentions blood dripping from a pipe clogged with bodies.

> An overhead pipe is cracked and blood drips on them from it.  Oddly enough, some of the protestors have just been taken into one of the tanks.  Putting two and two together, Quatermass exclaims, “That pipe has been blocked by human pulp!”

You can view the scene in question in the video clip below.

Comment: Almost certainly this. Quatermass and his  friends are pouring oxygen into a dome, to kill alien invaders there. The invaders persuade a group of workers to come and see that this is wrong and they are destroying an innocent project. When the workers get there they are seized and crushed into a "human pulp" to block the pipe.

Comment: It is almost certainly this movie, but be careful. The one the link takes you to is the six part series the BBC made. Personally I find that version quite boring. The original poster may be asking about the Hammer Horror version? Much, much better IMHO. Hammer remade two of the Doctor Who dalek series as movies, and the first three Quatermas series

Comment: @A. Kaye - Thanks for pointing this out. The IMDB and Wikipedia links and the review did pertain to the movie, but the video clip was indeed from the TV series. I've now replaced it with a clip from the movie, and it fits the description better than the TV clip did, so that is likely the version the OP saw.